# How to allow authenticated user to view others data?

Tags: views, 8, webforms

My sales staff fills in a webform with uploaded pics
The Service department needs to view the submitted pics for the installations.
Wondering if a module is needed to allow an authenticated user to view the submitted data entered by someone else.  Currently my view only shows up when the user is an administrator. Webform Views Integration works Great... if only my Service Dept users could see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in people/permissions
Checked the authenticated user columns for webform submissions and pages.
Now it works as it needs to.